# Changing Style of WMS dynamically with a select box in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, wms

I have a Leaflet WMS Layer

```
mylayer = new L.tileLayer.wms('https://{s}.url.com/wms?', {
    mylayers: 'Workspace:mylayer',
    format: 'image/png',
    transparent: true,
    styles: 'sld1',
});
mylayer.addTo(map);
```

I have others styles sld2, sld3, sld4 how can change styles dynamically with a select box. I tried to use `.setParams` but it does not work:

```
<select id="styles" onchange="layer.setParams({styles: this.value});">
    <option selected="selected"  value="sld1">sld1</option>
    <option value="sld2">sld2</option>
</select>
```

This is the code:

```
<script>
        
    var map = L.map('map', {center: [46.3079204858171, 6.29013173213052 ], zoom: 7});     

    var tilemap = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.fr/osmfr/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {attribution: '&copy; Openstreetmap France | &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'}).addTo(map);            

mylayer = new L.tileLayer.wms('https://{s}.url.com/wms?', {
    mylayers: 'Workspace:mylayer',
    format: 'image/png',
    transparent: true,
    styles: 'sld1',
});

<select id="styles" onchange="mylayer.setParams({styles: this.value});">
    <option selected="selected"  value="sld1">sld1</option>
    <option value="sld2">sld2</option>
</select>

</script>
```

Comment: what doesn't work? what requests are sent to the server?

Comment: now i change styles just by change name sld1 by sld2 , but me i want to change it using select box like when i change layers , i find this methode of .setParams but doesn't work the show me white page.

Comment: Place your select box after the ending </script> tag.

Comment: i tried to place it after </scripte> but the probleme that don't create any select box in the map to switch between styles!